# java string.split() regex help

Tags: java, regex, string

If I have a variable string which stores a different section of characters from a larger string, how can I split the larger string aroung the smaller string using the split command with regex?

For example the string variable may store "def"
The larger string may be "abcdefghi"

When the split command is preformed with the regex input as the string variable, the resulting split will be like this:

abc
ghi

edit: here is the code

```
String string = new String("2+22*5-1*2");
String multiply = new String("22*5");

int leftNum = Integer.parseInt(multiply.split("\\*")[0]);
int rightNum = Integer.parseInt(multiply.split("\\*")[1]);

System.out.println(string);
System.out.println(multiply);
System.out.println(leftNum * rightNum);

//the following should print "2+"
String left = string.split(multiply)[0];
System.out.println(left);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string.split("\\Q" + substring + "\\E");
```

The \Q and \E escape out metacharacters for you.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I read about that but when I tried it I only used one \ and no quotations so I didn't escape the character properly.

Answer (score 1):

`"abcdefghi".split("def")` will yield `{"abc", "ghi"}`.

Comment: You mean yield {"abc", "ghi"}

Comment: I i've been trying that. The line of code is like this: System.out.println(string.split(""+substr)[0]); but this just prints out the whole string without making the split.

Comment: What are the values of `string` and `substr`?

Comment: String string = new String("2+22*5-1*2");
String substring = new String("22*5");

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to escape the `*` to use the content of `multiply` as a regexp (the parameter of `split` is a regular expression):

```
 String regexp = multiply.replace("*", "\\*");
 String left = string.split(regexp)[0];
```

This should print the expected result (`2+`)